# Vue v-bind - access array object from another array loop

Tags: html, arrays, vue.js

I'm working on a project where I created a table component which is used on multiple pages with different configuration. Every table has it's configuration in a separate file where I store keys, titles and size classes for each column.

Data for each table body come from REST calls and they are loaded dynamically, paginated and then displayed.

```
<template slot="thead">
    <tr>          
        <th v-for="item in headers" :key="item.id" :class="item.classes">{{item.title}}</th>        
    </tr>      
</template>      
<template slot="tbody">        
    <tr v-for="skill in paginatedSkills" 
        :key="skill.id" 
        v-on:click="selectRow(skill)" 
        v-bind:class="{selectedRow: selectedSkill === skill}"
    >          
        <td class="cell-l">{{skill.name}}</td>          
        <td class="cell-m">{{skill.owner}}</td>          
        <td class="cell-s">{{skill.complexity}}</td>          
        <td class="cell-full">{{skill.description}}</td>        
    </tr>      
</template>
```

What I want to do is to avoid writing size class for every single cell in the `tbody` loop. I was hoping to get index of looped object and use it to retrieve the class from config object which is used to populate cells in `thead`.

```
<tr v-for="(skill, index) in paginatedSkills" ...>
        <td class="{headers[index].classes}">{{skill.name}}</td>
```

Using index on headers will return the correct item but as a string so obviously classes are not accessible. Any idea how to tweak it?

This options are no go, failing on compile

```
<td :class="{JSON.parse(headers[index]).classes}">{{skill.name}}</td>
<td :class="{JSON.parse(headers)[index].classes}">{{skill.name}}</td>
<td :class="{{JSON.parse(headers[index]).classes}}">{{skill.name}}</td>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set class from a variable/property you have two options:

```
<td v-bind:class="headers[index].classes">{{skill.name}}</td>
<td :class="headers[index].classes">{{skill.name}}</td>
```

No need for curly braces here since `v-bind` already expects JS expression.

**Update:**

What you can also do, is to associate keys of `skill` object (name, owner, complexity, description) with their header, so each item of `headers` array will also have for example `key` property used to access value from `skill` object:

```
headers: [
    { id: 1, classes: 'cell-l', title: 'title', key: 'name' },
    { id: 2, classes: 'cell-s', title: 'title', key: 'owner' },
    ...
]
```

Thus, your code can be simplified the following way:

```
<tr v-for="skill in paginatedSkills" ...>          
    <td v-for="header in headers" v-bind:class="header.classes">{{skill[header.key]}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: It's not working, I'm getting Vue warn: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'classes' of undefined"

Comment: @dallows I just noticed, you probably have 4 elements in `headers` but trying to access it using index from `paginatedSkills` which is of different length and contain different data. You probably need to hardcode indexes like that: `<td v-bind:class="headers[0].classes">{{skill.name}}</td>`

Comment: That brings me back to hard-coding only this time it's less obvious what's happening, compared to using exact class name

Comment: @dallows Maybe less obvious but still keeps your class names at the single place. Anyway, see update to the answer

Comment: after update it works and it's even better solution than what I had before